# echo category in rss feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, categories

I am pulling an rss feed into my page templates using the default /feed.php. I can echo out the title, permalink and description just fine, but I can't seem to get the categories to display. Ideally I would like to use the category to insert a background image into a div by class.
This is what I have:

```
<?php if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');  
$feed = fetch_feed('http://www.*link to the feed*'); 
$limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(50); 
$items = $feed->get_items(0, $limit); 
}
if ($limit == 0) echo 'The feed is either empty or unavailable.';
else foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
<div class="feedItem">
<div class="<?php echo $item->get_categories(); ?>"></div>
<ul>
<li class="feedtitle"><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"     
target="_blank"> <?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a> </li>
<li class="feeddate"><?php echo $item->get_date('m/d/y'); ?></li>
<li><p><?php echo($item->get_description()); ?></p></li>
</ul>   
</div><!--item-->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But the `<?php echo $item->get_categories(); ?>` only echos out `<div class="Array"></div>`

How do I get the names of the categories from the rss feed?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code.

```
<div class="<?php echo $item->get_categories(); ?>"></div>
```

You're putting the result of `get_categories` in the `class` attribute of your `<div>`.

According to the [documentation](http://simplepie.org/api/class-SimplePie_Item.html), `get_categories` returns an `Array`.  Therefore, `<div class="Array"></div>` is exactly what's expected.

I assume you'd rather see something like `<div class="category1 category2 category3"></div>`?  If so, you'll need to work with the array that `get_categories` returns.

Edited code, based on http://simplepie.org/api/class-SimplePie_Category.html

```
<?php
$cat_terms = array();
for ($item->get_categories() as $cat) {
    $cat_terms[] = $cat->get_term();
}
?>
<div class="<?php echo implode(" ", $cat_terms); ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Well, it's closer than it was, certainly.  I'm having trouble getting it to output the category slug however.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I keep ending up with `<div class="2c7a995d84e7b742dfbab421faf618d6 ... eb7ebfd049afb5d92683cf49b9194cd2">`  I've tried get the category object of the slug and that empties the feed all together.

Comment: Ah!  The `_toString()` method returns an md5 hash.  You probably need the `get_term()` method.

Comment: actually I tried something like that and it didn't work. I read the simplePie documentation and the only things the get_categories gets are labels, terms and schema.  What I ended up using was this `<?php foreach ($item->get_categories() as $category) {echo " " . $category->get_label();} ?>` This will work for the time being.  Now I need to figure out how to convert the label to a slug, which I'll bet is a question for a different thread.  Thanks